# How to get exact binary representation of big numbers in c/c++?

Tags: c, binary, long-integer, biginteger, scientific-notation

I am trying to convert big numbers to binary in C/C++ and Java but if i take input in plain decimal like `998446744073709551615` output is correct but if i will use scientific notation ex : `1.7334e+32` then binary representation comes wrong.

I have tested from double and BigDecimals from binary in C/C++ and Java.

***String to Long Double in C/C++ Test :***
https://ideone.com/EeOyNP

***String to Big Decimal in Java Test :***
https://ideone.com/OAvx7q

The problem is with numbers which are represented in more than `64 bits` aren't represented in scientific notation somehow .

Check out the output below.

**Output from C/C++ Code :**

> Input = 998446744073709551615 Expected Binary =
>   1101100010000000111011011001111011110011001010110011111111111111111111
>
> Output :  Successfully parsed strtold (C-Style): 9.98447e+20 Binary :
>   1101100010000000111011011001111011110011001010110100000000000000000000
>
> stringstream parsed stringstream (C++ Style): 9.98447e+20 Binary :
>   1101100010000000111011011001111011110011001010110100000000000000000000
>
> showBitDiff statistics :  Total Bits 70 Bits 49 Bits matched 21 Bits
>   not matched

**Output from Java Code :**

> Decimal String Part  :
>
> decimalString  : 998446744073709551615 
>   Scientific notation : 9.984467440737096E20
>
> Decimal-String Radix Info :
>   Binary :
>   1101100010000000111011011001111011110011001010110011111111111111111111
>   Decimal : 998446744073709551615 
>   Hexa : 0x36203B67BCCACFFFFF 
>   Bit length : 70
>
> Exponent String Part :
>   exponentString  : 9.984467440737096E20
>
> Exponent String Radix Info :
>   Binary :
>   1101100010000000111011011001111011110011001010110100001011110100000000
>   Decimal : 998446744073709600000 
>   Hexa : 0x36203B67BCCAD0BD00 
>   Bit length : 70
>
> Both BigInts are not equal

How do i solve this problem and represent big numbers correctly in C/C++? 
i don't want solution in java i just used java for testing purpose because it has bigDecimal Class for very large arbitrary numbers thanks.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are different languages.  C++ has `std::bitset`, `std::string` and `std::vector`, the C language doesn't.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes i know c++ has std::bitset . but my problem is related to both languages long double which is both in c/c++ so i want to know where is representation wrong.

Comment: @Ron but the problem is not with language its with data type that is present in both languages that is "long double data type" so thats why i added that in there.

Comment: @Ron ok i will remove c++ tag but still i don't think it necessary to do so because my question was tested in both languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you first convert to double to represent your decimal in exponent representation then of course it is wrong. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic. *TLDR;* If you have more different numbers than states (2^128) you will have gaps. Thats what double is designed for from the beginning. If you require an exact representations of your actual number do not convert it into a floating point representation.

Comment: Then how will i get exact binary representation of big numbers if will not convert it into long double. because i want numbers > 64bits and that can only be represented in long double.

Comment: Are you able/allowed to use libraries? Additionally what type of numbers do you get rational or real numbers?

Comment: Yes we can use inbuilt libraries also i already have used them in my code and i get real numbers and followed by zeros filled in so thats why i am getting wrong binary representation . But for numbers in < 64bits they hold correct but dont know for numbers > 64bits they dont represent exact number while long double has 96bits.

Comment: You sure you are using real numbers? Your examples and telling hints you are only using integers/natural numbers.

Comment: Actually it uses both first it uses decimal integers and print its binary representation then it again converts decimal to scientific notation for long doubles there it could be real number based on conversion . then again its prints binary which has the problem there representing binary because of conversion is rounding off truncating bits i guess .